# VBA VLookup from Another Workbook without opening it

Tags: vba

I have two workbooks. The one the Sub is in, and another called "Help.xlsm"

In my main workbook, I want search for a SKUID, which I get from my input box, then find that SKUID on the second workbook (Help.xlsm) on a Worksheet named "Lead Times," and then return the value from a cell 9 spaces to the right on that sheet. I'd prefer not to open the second workbook, though. I just want it to retrieve that data from it, and give me a message box with the info.

My question/issue, is I can't seem to get my reference to the other workbook to work properly, and pull that info. I always get a Compile Error: Syntax Error message.

```
Sub LeadTime()

Dim SKUID As String
Dim LTM As String
SKUID = InputBox("What is the SKU you'd like to know the lead time on?")

LTM = "=('C:\Users\gtn0717\Desktop\[Help.xlsm].Worksheets("Lead Times")'.Columns("A:A").Find(What:=SKUID).Offset(0, 9))"


    On Error Resume Next

    MsgBox (LTM)

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox ("That SKU doesn't exist here, you son of a bitch")
    Else
        Err.Clear
    End If
     End Sub
```

Comment: your quotes inside the string should be doubled.

Comment: Around "Lead Times" and the "A:A"?

Comment: That seems to just return a value of my path. It doesn't do the work I'm asking it to do.

Comment: `LTM` is a `String`... it doesn't "do any work." You're putting code into quotes, making it just text. That doesn't do anything.

Comment: I want LTM to be the value in a cell on the second workbook, that is 9 characters to the right of the variable (SKUID) I searched for, which will be a string. Not the whole path of the second workbook. So the work I want it to do, is go to that second workbook, find my variable (SKUID), then return the value 9 spaces to the right of that variable on the second workbook. But without opening the workbook.

Comment: This is not possible... It seems like you are conflating VBA and formulas.